# A/B Testing and Duplicate Content

Tags: google, ab-testing, seo

Now that Google can crawl/index content from JavaScript, how are page variants treated by Google by serving a slightly different versions when A/B testing?

Is it advisable to add references to the JavaScript files that are generated by Obtimizely or Visual Website Optimizer in Robots.txt?

Neil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this article has some helpful information:

http://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-analytics-adds-split-testing-feature-google-website-optimizer-to-be-discontinued/44398/

> - Use rel=”canonical” to tell Google which of the test pages is the    main page that should be indexed.
> - Once the test is complete, use 301 redirects to redirect users and       Google to the main/final page. (There could be links or bookmarks
>     pointing to one of the variations.)